Introducing custom-role in my Django based E-commerce application
I completed finish my Django E-commerce web-application. And now I want to add the facility of customer roles(admin,staff,merchant,customer). I'm having problems configuring this with my project. I'd really appreciate if someone can help me through the process. I am sharing the details of project.
My existing Customer model
class Customer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) -change I made to add CustomUser model
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    state = models.TextField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

My CustomerUser model that I want to introduce in my project
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ROLES=(
        ('admin', 'Admin'),
        ('staff', 'Staff'),
        ('merchant', 'Merchant'),
        ('user', 'User'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=8,choices=ROLES,default='Customer')

    def is_admin(self):
        return self.role == 'admin'

    def is_staff(self):
        return self.role == 'staff'

    def is_merchant(self):
        return self.role == 'merchant'

The login, logout and registration stopped working as soon as I added this CustomUser model into my project.

Kindly share the exact error details

You can actually add these roles on Django Admin

The login, logout and registration stopped working as soon as I added this CustomUser model into my project.  What user model did you use before?

@VinayVishwakarma Thank you but I resolved the problem
